# Is there a way to concatenate the content of the respective cells of two different n * n data-frames within cells in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to concatenate the content of the respective cells of two different n * n data-frames **within** cells in pandas?

For example: Say I have two data-frames `df1` and `df2`.

`df1` looks like this:

| Index | Score_1 | Score_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Family_1 | 123 | 456 |
| Family_2 | 789 | 1011 |

`df2` looks like this:

| Index | Score_1 | Score_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Family_1 | A | B |
| Family_2 | C | D |

I want to make a third data-frame that takes each n * n cell from `df1` and concatenate it with the content from a respective n * n cell from `df2` and make a third data-frame that looks something like this:

| Index | Score_1 | Score_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Family_1 | A:123 | B:456 |
| Family_2 | C:789 | D:1011 |

Just to make sure: One table has strings and the other has numbers but I want to do string concatenation so using `str()` is necessary is fine.

`pd.concat()` concats whole data-frames like this:

| Index | Score_1 | Score_2 | Score_1 | Score_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Family_1 | A | B | 123 | 456 |
| Family_2 | C | D | 789 | 1011 |

I am trying to superimpose the cells instead.

I tried to do it from scratch with `zip` and `intertuples` roughly like this:

```py
for i,j in zip(df1.itertuples(),df2.itertuples()):
    n=1
    while n < len(i):
        print(i[n], ":", j[n])
        n = n + 1
    print('\n')
```

Whose output is along the lines of:

> A:123
>
> B:456
>
> C:789
>
> D:1011

Which I think I can reroute to dicts or an intermediate file and reshape from there but that seems a little unwieldy. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can temporarily set "Index" as index, convert to string, and `add`:

```
out = (df2
 .set_index('Index') # skip if already index
 .add(':'+df1.set_index('Index').astype(str))
 .reset_index()      # skip if already index
)
```

output:

```
      Index Score_1 Score_2
0  Family_1   A:123   B:456
1  Family_2   C:789  D:1011
```

If "Index" is already the index:

```
out = df2.add(':'+df1.astype(str))
```

output:

```
         Score_1 Score_2
Index                   
Family_1   A:123   B:456
Family_2   C:789  D:1011
```